# What is the purpose of an external static variable?

Tags: c, static

K&R c page 83 says the following:

> The static declaration, applied to an external variable or function, limits the scope of that object to the rest of the source file being compiled. External static thus provides a way to hide names like `buf` and `bufp` in the `getch`-`ungetch` combination, which must be external so they can be shared, yet which should not be visible to users of `getch` and `ungetch`.

How could any external variable be visible in another file without an `extern` modifier on the variable in the new file anyway? Is there some type of added protection for variables with the static storage class?

What is the purpose of using static on an external variable? Any simple examples?

---

Edit:

I think I'm confusing people with my question, so I'm going to write it out as code. I'm expanding the idea to include functions as well:

contents of file 1

```
void somefunc(void);
int x;
int main()
{
    ....
}
void somefunc(void)
{
    ....
}
```

file 2

```
int x;
void somefunc(void);
void somefunc(void)
{
    ....
}
```

Notice that `int x` and `somefunc()` in file 1 are not visible in file 2, and vice versa. That is, *unless we include an `extern` modifier on `int x` and/or `somefunc()` in either file, the matching function and variable names from the files will be invisible to one another.*

Why would we need to put `static` on one of these variables or functions to prevent the variable or function from being visible in the other file if we already have to knowingly use an `extern` to make the function or variable visible in the other file?

The code would need to look like this for contents of file 2 to be visible in file 1:

```
extern void somefunc(void);
extern int x;
int main()
{
    ....
}
void somefunc(void)
{
    ....
}
```

file 2

```
int x;
void somefunc(void);
void somefunc(void)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that "external" meant `extern` and not simply that they are at file scope?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's not talking about the `extern` modifier. It's talking about the `static` modifier on external variables.

Comment: I believe that "external" most likely means "global" in the context of this question.

Comment: For anyone else who might be looking for this passage (since it's not on page 83 of my K&R copy) - this is from the first paragraph of 4.6 "Static Variables" in the 2nd Edition.

Comment: Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable

Answer (score 2):

Quoting what you quoted:

> External static thus provides a way to hide names like `buf` and `bufp` in the `getch`-`ungetch` combination, which must be external so they can be shared, yet which should not be visible to users of `getch` and `ungetch`.

It just means that the static variables are not function scoped static variables. They are external to functions but they are static in the file.

Making them static in a file makes them visible to `getch` and `ungetch` but not to other functions in other files.

**Update, in response to edited question**

You said,

> Notice that `int x` and `somefunc()` in file 1 are not visible in file 2, and vice versa. That is, unless we include an `extern` modifier on `int x` and/or `somefunc()` in either file, the matching function and variable names from the files will be invisible to one another.

That is an erroneous conclusion.

The line

```
int x;
```

equivalent to:

```
extern int x;
int x;
```

The line

```
void somefunc(void);
```

is equivalent to:

```
extern void somefunc(void);
```

If you compile the "file 1" and "file 2" and link the resulting object files to create an executable, you will get linker errors to the effect that `int x` and `void somefunc(void)` are multiply defined.

In order to keep them visible only in the respective files, you will have to make them `static` in the file scope.

```
static int x;
static void somefunc(void);
```

Comment: Yes, but how could these variables be visible in the other files to begin with. The only way another file could see them is if they're declared with an `extern` modifier in the new file. `static` therefore seems redundant.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you have three separate files, two of which have variables with the same name, and you want to "see" the variables from specifically one of those files in the third file.

Comment: `static` is not redundant. It makes sure that no other compilation unit can not use that variable. If you don't make a variable `static`, other compilation units *could* us it, be it by error or by malicious intent.

Comment: Your second comment is another argument for using `static` variables where it makes sense.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: it's confusing, but the word "external" is **not** the same as the keyword "extern".  As R Sahu mentions, "external" means the variable is outside of a function (it's at file scope).  It doesn't mean the the variable has external linkage (which the `static` keyword suppresses in this case).

Comment: I wasn't confused about the difference between an external variable or the `extern` modifier. I'm going to edit my question. I think I'm confusing people.

Comment: `
The line

int x;

equivalent to:

extern int x;
`
NO!

Comment: @user1720897, I said `int x;` is equivalent to `extern int x; int x;` If you don't agree, offer some explanation. "NO!" does not explain it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference of terminology between K&R2 and the C Standard.

K&R2 uses the wording *external variable* for a file-scope variable, and uses the wording *external static* to specify a file-scope variable declared with the static storage class specifier. In the C Standard the word *external* is usually reserved for linkage and not for lexical scope.

Comment: The C standard also makes a distinction between an "external declaration" (C11 6.9/4: "These are described as "external"
because they appear outside any function (and hence have ﬁle scope)") and "external linkage".  It's confusing terminology, but it is in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

1. What are the uses of the keyword static?

This simple question is rarely answered completely.  Static has three distinct uses in C:

(a)    A variable declared static within the body of a function maintains its value between function invocations.

(b)    A variable declared static within a module[1](http://www.rmbconsulting.us/a-c-test-the-0x10-best-questions-for-would-be-embedded-programmers), (but outside the body of a function) is accessible by all functions within that module. It is not accessible by functions within any other module.  That is, it is a localized global.

(c)    Functions declared static within a module may only be called by other functions within that module. That is, the scope of the function is localized to the module within which it is declared.

Most candidates get the first part correct.  A reasonable number get the second part correct, while a pitiful number understand answer (c).

From [A ‘C’ Test: The 0×10 Best Questions for Would-be Embedded Programmers](http://www.rmbconsulting.us/a-c-test-the-0x10-best-questions-for-would-be-embedded-programmers)

Comment: I don't really understand what a module is yet, but (b) and (c) were discussed in terms of a function in that excerpt I posted, and (a) is discussed on the same page. My question was really why would we need to do this. I've edited my original question if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Think about such a situation:
If you have three files, file1 and file 2 both have `int x`, but with different values, then in file3 you have `extern int x`. How could the compiler know which x you want? That's when you need `extern`.